# How to find classes that are not used in any CSS selector?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML excerpt from a page:

```
<style type="text/css">
.existing-class {
  background-color: #000;
}
</style>
<div class="existing-class non-existing-class"></div>
```

It has 2 classes applied. Here is the thing: `non-existing-class` is not defined anywhere in the CSS available in the page, however `div` is using it.

My question is: How can a developer programmatically detect elements in the page which are using classes that are not actually defined in the loaded CSS?

Comment: First of all, there is not really such thing as a “non-existing class”. The class exists, _because_ you put `non-existing-class` into the class attribute of the element. You should first of all let go of the thinking, “here’s a class, so it must have something to do with CSS” - of course not. It _classifies_ the element as belonging to a certain class, that’s it. Now if you want to re-phrase the question to “I want to find classes that are not used in any CSS selector”, it starts making more sense. [...]

Comment: To do this programmatically, you would have to loop over all elements to find all classes, and over all stylesheets to go through all the rules, and see if their selectors contain the class in any way. Of course this is not going to be trivial, since you might not only be looking for `.non-existing-class`, but f.e. `[class="non-existing-class"]` or even `[class*="existing"]`, which could match elements with the class as well ...

Comment: @CBroe: I see. It makes sense your comment. The 2 systems are actually separated. The reason for me picturing this in that way is because I was seeing this from the perspective of the CSS engine in the browser and the renderer component as well. From their POV, they actually need to correlate a class name marking an element to a set of rendering features.

Comment: Okay checkout my update answer

Comment: You can do one thing get all class name used in css file and then make regular expression find name of classes which does not belongs to this regular expression.

Comment: Be careful when doing this sort of test. There's plenty of code which depends on JS being able to find classes without CSS ever going near it.

Comment: I have edited the question, trying to make it less broad as requested by the community

Comment: @Andry The answer is still "you cant", when using HTML and CSS. Would you like to add the [tag:javascript] tag to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, there you go ;)
Take a look at the script I have created, especially `getUndefinedClasses` function.

```js
function httpGet(theUrl) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send( null );
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
}


function getAllCSSClasses(cssdata) {
  var re = /\.(.+)\{/g;
  var m;
  let classes = [];
  do {
    m = re.exec(cssdata);
    if (m) {
      for(let key in m) {
        if(
           (typeof m[key] == "string") && 
           (classes.indexOf(m[key]) == -1) &&
           (m[key].indexOf(".") == -1)
          )
          classes.push(m[key].replace(/\s/g, " "));
      }
    }
  } while (m);
  return classes;
}

function getAllClasses() {
  var csses = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]'); 
   var classes = []
  for (i = 0; i < csses.length; ++i) {
    // let styledata = httpGet(csses[i].href);
    var styledata = ".hi{ display: none; }";
    var cclasses = getAllCSSClasses(styledata);
    var classes = Object.assign([], classes, cclasses);
    classes.concat(cclasses);
  }
  return classes;
}

function getHTMLUsedClasses() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var unique = function (list, x) {
    if (x != "" && list.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        list.push(x);
    }
    return list;
  };
  var trim = function (x) { return x.trim(); };
  var htmlclasses = [].reduce.call(elements, function (acc, e) {
    return e.className.split(' ').map(trim).reduce(unique, acc);
  }, []);
  return htmlclasses;
}


function getUndefinedClasses(cssclasses, htmlclasses) {
  var undefinedclasses = [];
  for (let key in htmlclasses) {
    if(cssclasses.indexOf(htmlclasses[key])  == -1 ) {
       undefinedclasses.push(htmlclasses[key]);
    }
  }
  return undefinedclasses;
}

var cssclasses = getAllClasses();
var htmlclasses = getHTMLUsedClasses();

console.log("Undefined classes : " + getUndefinedClasses(cssclasses, htmlclasses))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hi there">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="hi"></div>
  <div class="there"></div>
  <div class="there_thier_333"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is done:

1. I get all the classnames from the css data, (you can pass the css
   data by various means).
2. Then I get all the classes used in HTML elements, both of these are recorded in arrays.
3. Finally, I simply push the classes which were used by HTML Elements but not found in the cssclasses array which leaves you with the undefined classes in CSS.

([jsbin here needed](https://jsbin.com/cexasupuvu/1/edit?html,js,console,output))

Comment: `[class*="he"] { background: red; }` would of course apply to `<div class="there">` - but your script would not find it. Yet if the class was removed from the HTML element, the visual output would change - so I don’t think we could classify this as an “unused class” in this case either.

Comment: Well, you can modify the regex in the script to detect any type of class declaration

:) including the one you specified.

Comment: Well _you_ would have to do that, if you want this to be considered a full answer to the question :) Plus, I rather doubt this would actually be as easy as you think it is.

Comment: That's right, making a general purpose class regex would be difficult,, 
but we can have an array of all possible class name declaration methods, 
and iterate over each declaration method to collect classnames.

you agree?

and the reason I havent implemented it in the script is because the original question does not point in that direction, if the user wants, he can customize it according to his needs :)

Comment: Yeah, my main point here is that you can not simply look for “full class names” only. The attribute selector allows for stuff such as starts with, ends with or contains somewhere in between. It could demand that the class starts with `he`, contains `he` anywhere, or ends with `he` - only the middle one would apply to the class `there` ...

Comment: Yup ;( sadly it does fail in cases where an unhandled class declaration method is used in the stylesheet.

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for the downvote? The approach can be liked or not but it is a valid one...

Comment: Yep! , and wow <3 someone prettified my answer :) Thank you for the edit @Stephane